# Get max value of a long xml list with several conditions in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

The query

https://build.opnfv.org/ci/api/xml?tree=jobs[displayName,url,lastBuild[building,builtOn,timestamp]]&xpath=/hudson/job[lastBuild/builtOn=%22lf-pod2%22][lastBuild/building=%22false%22]&wrapper=hudson

returns a long xml list and I want to take the job with higher timestamp in the same query. Is it possible to concatenate conditions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to get the maximum ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365640/xpath-to-get-the-maximum-id)

Comment: This query is a more complex containing several conditions. I tried to use what is explained in [XPath to get the maximum ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365640/xpath-to-get-the-maximum-id) but didn't manage to make it work...  So, adding this `[lastBuild[not(//lastBuild/timestamp>timestamp)]]` doesn't help...

Comment: I am not seeing any additional condition in the question

Comment: what I mean is combining builtOn='lf-pod2' and building='false' works, but how to have another condition to get the max timestamp of that list?

Comment: @splash58 it isn't explicitly explained but OP's initial XPath is there in the 'xpath' query string parameter of the URL : `/hudson/job[lastBuild/builtOn="lf-pod2"][lastBuild/building="false"]`

Comment: @har07 I, probably, was too sleepy to take url into account :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the two existing predicates when checking for maximum timestamp, so the additional predicate should be as follow :

```
[lastBuild[
    not(timestamp < 
        /hudson/job[lastBuild/builtOn='lf-pod2'][lastBuild/building='false']/lastBuild/timestamp
    )
]]
```

Since `builtOn` and `building` are in the sampe `lastBuild` parent, it can be simplified as follow :

```
[lastBuild[
    not(timestamp < 
        /hudson/job/lastBuild[builtOn='lf-pod2' and building='false']/timestamp
    )
]]
```

Having said that, this [URL](https://build.opnfv.org/ci/api/xml?tree=jobs[displayName,url,lastBuild[building,builtOn,timestamp]]&xpath=/hudson/job[lastBuild/builtOn=%22lf-pod2%22][lastBuild/building=%22false%22][lastBuild[not(timestamp%20%3C%20/hudson/job[lastBuild/builtOn=%22lf-pod2%22][lastBuild/building=%22false%22]/lastBuild/timestamp)]]&wrapper=hudson) which contains the above additional predicate successfully return one element in the result :

```
<hudson>
  <job>
    <displayName>fuel-deploy-baremetal-daily-master</displayName>
    <url>https://build.opnfv.org/ci/job/fuel-deploy-baremetal-daily-master/</url>
    <lastBuild>
      <building>false</building>
      <timestamp>1464739201208</timestamp>
      <builtOn>lf-pod2</builtOn>
    </lastBuild>
  </job>
</hudson>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!